# Echoing the login script if the user isn't logged in

Tags: php

I am receiving an syntax error when using this code, what I want is for the log in script to only display if the user isn't logged in but receiving an error on the line start of  line 4:

```
<?php
if($_SESSION['loggedin'] != TRUE){

echo "Already a member?&nbsp;
<form id=\"loginform\" method=\"post\" action="$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];"
<label for=\"username\"> Email Address:</label>
<input type=\"text\" name=\"liusername\"/>
<br>
<label for=\"password\"> Password:</label>
<input type=\"text\" name=\"lipassword\" id=\"password\" />
</div>
<div class=\"submit\">
<input name=\"lisubmit\" type=\"submit\" value=\"submit\">
</div>\n";

}else{
 echo 
"<a href = logout.php>Log out</A>\n";
?>
}
```

Comment: Add `session_start();` on top first.

Comment: I have got this at the top of the page, there is some other scripting above it

Comment: You ended your string value after `action=` by using an unescaped `"` … In general, you should not use echo to output large parts of mostly static HTML code – better to leave the PHP parser, write HTML code directly, and only use PHP in it where necessary. And since an unhandled output of `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` is a XSS vulnerability – best to just leave the action atribute value blank if you just want the form sent to the current page anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the form opening part to the following. That should make the code work:

```
<form id=\"loginform\" method=\"post\" action='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."'>
```

And take out the '?>' out of the else {}. Let me know if it doesn't help.

Comment: @user3480862 mark this answer as correct and question as solved ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your `echo` is not correct .

Try this code :

```
<?php
if($_SESSION['loggedin'] != TRUE){

echo "Already a member?&nbsp;
<form id=\"loginform\" method=\"post\" action=".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];"
<label for=\"username\"> Email Address:</label>
<input type=\"text\" name=\"liusername\"/>
<br>
<label for=\"password\"> Password:</label>
<input type=\"text\" name=\"lipassword\" id=\"password\" />
</div>
<div class=\"submit\">
<input name=\"lisubmit\" type=\"submit\" value=\"submit\">
</div>\n";

}else{
 echo 
"<a href = logout.php>Log out</A>\n";
?>
}
```

Comment: With single quotes, the newlines chars (\n) will not be interpreted, you must delete them

Answer (score 0):

**Closing bracket not in PHP context**:

```
}else{
echo "<a href = logout.php>Log out</A>\n";
?>
}
```

should be

```
    echo "<a href = logout.php>Log out</A>\n";
}
?>
```

Plus, already mentioned, **wrong variable concatenation**:

```
"$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];"
```

must be

```
" . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "
```

**session not started**:

```
session_start(); // Before http body, before $_SESSION usage
```

Besides that, you shouldn't put (PHP) logic and (HTML) markup in the same file / context.